# Could we apply foreach loop in controller without accessing view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to check/traverse the table data to delete my user from extra entries using foreach loop.

How can I retrieve my table from controller with foreach loop without accessing to any view.

```
public ActionResult Accept(int id = 0)
{
    Proposal_Requests prop_req = db.Proposal_Request.Find(id);
    if (prop_req == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    prop_req.Accept_Date = DateTime.Now;
    prop_req.Status = "Proposal Accepted";
    db.Entry(prop_req).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    foreach( var item in Proposal_Requests)
    {
   if(item.id!= prop_req.id)
   {
  if(item.std1 == prop_req.std1 || item.std1 = prop_req.std2 || item.std1 == prop_req.std3)
  {
    item.std1 = " " ;

   }
  if(item.std2 == prop_req.std1 || item.std2 == prop_req.std2 || item.std2 == prop_req.std3)
  {
    item.std2 = " " ;

  }
 if(item.std3 == prop_req.std1 || item.std3 == prop_req.std2 || item.std3 == prop_req.std3)
 {
    item.std3 = " " ;

 }
    }
    
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Proposal_Requests");
}
```

i want to delete the user id from all the requests when one of its request get accepted or disable all the requests created by that user.

**Proposal_Request** is the table from which i wanted to remove

> Std_Id (student id)

stored in one of its columns.

`Proposal_Requests prop_req = db.Proposal_Request.Find(id);`

when this id get accepted by the supervisor.

- All the students who are enrolled for this proposal get deleted from
  the other proposals.
- for this I'm using **foreach** loop so that every row of the table

  Proposal_Request get traversed and data matched to delete the student IDs from the other PROPOSALS with the same STD_ID as the accepted on.

Comment: There's a mistake here: `item.std1 = prop_req.std2` apart from that I can't understand what you're asking. What is PReq? What Table? Which user?

Comment: Proposal_Request is the table from which i wanted to remove `Std_Id (student id)` stored in one of its columns. 
`Proposal_Requests prop_req = db.Proposal_Request.Find(id);` 
when this id get accepted by the supervisor. 
All the students who are enrolled for this proposal get deleted from the other proposals. 
for this I'm using **foreach** loop so that every row of the table Proposal_Request get traversed and data matched to delete the student IDs from the other PROPOSALS with the same STD_ID as the accepted on.